# Sharepoint 2013 Apps Configuration on Premises

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

While configuring our SharePoint environment for APPS we Created a Generic/Blank Web Application as I was getting 404 error until I created the blank web app on port 80

But after that i am getting the below alert in health analyzer

> "A default zone url is pointing to the machine name of a web front
>   end.  Since this installation has more than one web front end, this
>   can result in a variety of errors including incorrect links and failed
>   operations."

Also from time to time we are having strange issues in our SharePoint  like the web sites open fine in IE 11 but in Chrome we will get 401 Unauthorized and according to this technet blog "https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/dbd7563e-52e7-4456-9102-74c9e4766646/can-not-access-sharepoint-2013-site-i-am-getting-401-unauthorized?forum=sharepointadmin" they suggest to keep the "IP address is in the Alternate Access Mapping collection for your site"

Can you suggest if that's valid approach and the errors we are having are related with AAM configuration ?

Comment: How many WFEs do you have? Do you have a load balancer which points traffic from a certain to the WFEs? If you do, make sure both your domains (the app domain and your :80 domain is in your alternate access mappings.

Comment: Hi Kevin We have 4 WFes and yes we use F5 as load balancer tool and for app domain we actually created a forward lookup zone pointing to the same Share point domain .So do we still need the app domain in AAM ?

Comment: I don't recommend having the app domain be the same as your other domain - this is for security reasons as the app domain is meant to be isolated. Do you have a host header? Check [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn144963(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: No We have a different app domain what i meant was we create a wildcard CNAME Record for the new app domain
pointed to the FQDN of the SharePoint Server .But for the apps to work i had to create a empty web app with no host header